# How to get channel name in string format using channel id in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, telegram

i have written a small code which sends message to discord channel, includes category and channel name and after that message. on discord is working fine, i get to see Category and channel name, but when i forward same to telegram, channel and category names are converted to numbers.

```
let content = '**'+message.channel.parent+'**\n';
    content += client.channels.get(message.channel.id)+'\n';
    content += message.content;
    message.attachments.forEach(attachment => {
      content += '\n' + attachment.proxyURL;     
    });
```

In telegram i see

> <#708416372987920394> // category name
> <#708416407007920158> // channel name
> <@&577534787502211073> // Role name

How to solve this, is there any way to convert text to plain text in discord and making category and channel name not clickable or modify the name bit.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this by using the `name` property of those channels

Also, using template literals helps keep your code cleaner

```js
const channel = client.channels.get(message.channel.id)
let content = `**${message.channel.parent.name}**\n${channel.name}\n${message.content}`

message.attachments.forEach(attachment => {
  content += `\n${attachment.proxyURL}`  
})
```

Comment: Thanks dear, your answer solved my issue for both category and channel name & now on fwding to telegram everything is ok.
However in message there is a Role attached, so when fwding is done, i see @deleted-role in discord and in Telegram i see its ID. Is there any way to remove any Roles attached to msg. 
Thanks again.